# More divs I use the more big gaps I get

Tags: css, html

I recenlty started using divs to arrange art on my pages in a very specific position. After I get what I think looks right I get this HUGE gap under all the divs. Seems the more div's I use the bigger the gap. I just want that gap gone. Any pros got an answer on this?

Here is my Code:

```
<div>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 12px; top: -20px; width: 970px; height: 0px;">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1285 devanco_ep_curimg" alt="dsm-napkin-top-TEMP" src="http://thedsmgroup.com/jason/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dsm-napkin-full.png" width="1001" height="131" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 65px; top: -20px; width: 450px; height: 100px; padding: 20px;">
        <div>
            <h5>We’re a creative full service marketing firm in Northern New Jersey.</h5>
            <h6>Creative Branding | Advertising | PR | Website Design | SEO | World Class Client Support</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div style="position: relative; left: 548px; top: -180px; width: 193px; height: 72px;">
    <a title="The DSM Group Is A Full Service Agency" href="http://thedsmgroup.com/jason/agency-2/">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1412" alt="dsm-who-we-are-btn" src="http://thedsmgroup.com/jason/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dsm-who-we-are-btn.png" width="251" height="66" />
    </a>
</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div style="position: relative; left: 750px; top: -339px; width: 193px; height: 72px;">
    <a title="The Most Complete Marketing Agency In NJ" href="http://thedsmgroup.com/jason/services/">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1411" alt="dsm-what-we-do-btn" src="http://thedsmgroup.com/jason/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dsm-what-we-do-btn.png" width="251" height="66" />
    </a>
</div>
&nbsp;
```

Comment: So...[can you point out the gap](http://jsfiddle.net/FpYqE/)?

Comment: why do you have your <div> tags wrapped in spaces?

Answer (score 3):

It's because of all of the top adjustments like `top:-339px`.

Relatively positioning an element doesn't really take it out of document flow, it just uses it's static space and moves it from there.  This means if you have an element like this...

```
.rel {
position:relative;
top:-100px;
}
```

...it is technically still filling that other space, so the other elements won't move up to fill the gap.

[Here's a jsFiddle to illustrate it.](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ8UA/)

Notice in the picture below how the gap is created.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens because You use the nbsp; or the space so more spaces will be covered by the div tag..also you have used position:relative and top:-100px that is also cause to have a huge gap on the div